# Как можно сделать что бы новые ячейки в tableLayoutPanel были такого же размера как те которые я создал в ручную Windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

Я делаю карточки товара в tableLayoutPanel но так как данные берутся из бдшки я не могу изначально знать сколько там будет карточек поэтому я вынужден в реальном времени добавлять новые ячейки но я столкнулся с проблемой что новые ячейки гораздо меньше чем старые как это исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Логично, что вы их как-то специфически добавляете, верно? Верно.. Раз так, то почему не показываете код добавления? Как вот мы можем помочь вам в решении проблемы, видя только картинку? Вообще, даже в WinForms уже давно есть механизм привязок данных, стоит посмотреть в его сторону, а не руками добавлять все.